# Registering Spring Controllers from Child Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application, but I want to split it up into one parent context and many smaller child contexts. Request mapping and security must be centralized, so one DispatcheServlet - having multiple servlets is not an option.

I want to create @Controllers and services in each of my child contexts, have Spring autowire child context beans into these controllers, but then have these controllers registered in parent context mappings.

Is this possible to do in Spring? I haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried. Provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hey have you found a solution to your problem?  Unfortunately I have the same issue